Как корректно передать массив матриц во фрагментный шейдер GLSL?
Мне надо передать массив из матриц в основной шейдер для рендеринга конечной картинки (теней). Я пытался передавать матрицы разными способами, но при преобразовании точки получается всегда один и тот-же ответ, (0,0,0). Дело не в настройках матрицах, так как через те-же матрицы корректно рендерятся карты теней.
Я пытался гуглить ответ, но в итоге пришёл лишь к процессу обычной передачи массива.
Вот способ передачи, который я нашёл
    int location = GL20.glGetUniformLocation(program, matrix);
FloatBuffer matricesBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16 * 6);
    for (int i = 0; i < this.matrix.length; i++) this.matrix[i].get(matricesBuffer);
    matricesBuffer.flip();

    GL20.glUniformMatrix4fv(location, false, matricesBuffer);

тест матрицы, который я проводил
uniform mat4 lightMatrix[6];


gl_FragColor = vec4((lightMatrix[3]*vec4(1,1,1,1)).rgb,1);

Вот карта теней. Это 1 из матриц (в примере выше под номером 3, их всего 6), я аналогично проверял все карты теней, всё работает. Тут карта теней натянута на плоскость, и отражена по XZ.
Красная точка - источник теней, из которой происходит рендер карт теней.


this.matrix[i].get(matricesBuffer); записывает все матрицы в начало буфера, затирая предыдущие, а не одну за другой

так я ищу корректный способ, это то, что я нашёл. Есть вариант записывать в массивы

Просто пишите матрицы друг за другом, и все должно будет передаться правильно.
